# Error when using ->paginate() with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

So I have this Topic controller on my forum. The Topic has many Posts and the Post belongs to the Topic.

```
class Topic 
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}

class Post 
{
    public function topic() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Topic');
    }
}
```

To get the informations about a Topic and all of the posts related to it, I do:

```
$query = Topic::where('id', $id)->with('posts');
```

But every time I try to add :

```
$query = $query->paginate(15)
```

and I use `$topic->title`, I get :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$title
```

Any idea? Thank you.

**EDIT : Oh and if I use `->get()` instead of `->paginate()` I don't have errors.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paginate(15)` call returns a `Paginator` object, holding many `Topic` items. If you want to get the `title` field of one of these items, you need to get one of them first. You can do this for example via:

```
$query->first()->title;
```

More likely, you will loop through the results and use them like that:

```
foreach($query as $key => $value)
{
    // do something here, $value contains a Topic object.
    $name = $value->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get that :).