# Laravel - Undefined property in a controller

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I"m trying to get lines from a Threads tables with comments. I do :

```
$posts = threads::where('published', '=', true)->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

$datas = [
        'posts' => $posts,
        'comments' => $posts->comments,
        'count_comments' => count($posts->comments)
];
```

Laravel returns :

Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$comments

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027615/error-when-using-paginate-with-laravel/25029361#25029361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$posts = threads::with('comments')->where('published', '=', true)->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

$comments = [];

foreach ($post in $posts)
{
    $comments[] = $post->comments;
}

$datas = [
    'posts' => $posts,
    'comments' => $comments,
    'count_comments' => count($comments)
];
```

Comment: Perfect solution. But there is no automatic solution to retrieve all tables associated by a foreign key ?